# Access Berare token from NextAouth Spotify Provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, spotify, next-auth, next.js13

i am new to Nextjs nad Oauth but i want NextAUth to use as a login but i want access the authentication token but i hav noit found something where i can read it out i only found this i wonder if i can edit this so i can add the token to the profile:

```
export interface SpotifyImage {
  url: string
}

export interface SpotifyProfile extends Record<string, any> {
  id: string
  display_name: string
  email: string
  images: SpotifyImage[]
}
export default function Spotify<P extends SpotifyProfile>(
  options: OAuthUserConfig<P>
): OAuthConfig<P> {
  return {
    id: "spotify",
    name: "Spotify",
    type: "oauth",
    authorization:
      "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?scope=user-read-email ",
    token: "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    userinfo: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me",
    profile(profile) {
      return {
        id: profile.id,
        name: profile.display_name,
        email: profile.email,
        image: profile.images?.[0]?.url,
      }
    },
    style: {
      logo: "/spotify.svg",
      logoDark: "/spotify.svg",
      bg: "#fff",
      text: "#2ebd59",
      bgDark: "#fff",
      textDark: "#2ebd59",
    },
    options,
  }
}
```